# Joomla custom file upload, process, save and search

Tags: joomla

I am new to joomla. I want to create a **custom image upload form** from which i can read the text of the uploaded image using a javascript ocr library and save the result to the database. User can then enter part of an image text to search in the database and return the image that contains the text.

I can do this with Node.js, however in Joomla, i'm having a bit of a pickle. The image below may help you understand what i plan to do. Please guide me to do this in Joomla. I have experience with javascript but not php.

[image]

Comment: Please post your Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

To upload an image and handle it in your own custom way you have to create a Joomla component. However if you already have a working NodeJS solution, I think the simplest solution for you would be to use some kind of iframe and put it inside of a Joomla article like that.

If you want to build a custom Joomla component, here is how: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component